# Return subset of JSON Object using Javascript map() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My question is if there is a simple way to return a subset of JSON object that will contain all 'columns' rather than specifying individually which 'columns' to return.

In particular, I have a multi-column csv file converted to JSON. The function below returns a subset of that object - just two 'columns' (as another object) if certain condition is met (in this case 'Name' is matched):

```
var firstSubArr = json.map(function(s) {
  if (s.Name === RegName) {
    return {
      'Price': s.Price,
      'Name': s.Name
    }
  }
}).filter(function(n) {
  return n !== undefined
});
```

Is there a simpler way to return "all columns" from json object as object rather that this:

```
return {'Price':s.Price,'Name':s.Name}?
```

Comment:
It is just a simple JSON structure after conversion from csv, eg:

```
`[
    {Name:'Sydney', Price:123, Type:'xyz', etc. 20 more... },
    etc.
    ]`
```

Comment 2: Yes filter may be an option as a couple of people suggested but what if my condition is a bit more complex, like:

```
    var fullPeriodArr= json.map( function (s) { 
    if(moment(s.Date,"YYYYMMDD").isSameOrBefore(currd) && moment(s.Date,"YYYYMMDD").isSameOrAfter(fullPeriodStart) && (s.Type==sid || s.Type==sid2)&& s.Name===RegName){return [s.Price, s.Name] 
    }
    }).filter( function (n) { 
    return n!== undefined
    });
```

**SOLUTION:**

All 3 respondents provided the clue, thanks! It was just “return every object in the array of objects that matches the condition”, or simply:

```
    var firstSubArr= json.filter( 

s =>  (moment(s.Date,"YYYYMMDD").isSameOrBefore(currd) && moment(s.Date,"YYYYMMDD").isSameOrAfter(fullPeriodStart) && (s.Type==sid  || s.Type==sid2) && s.Name===RegName)

);
```

. where time range 'from... to' is evaluated using moment.js lib and Date, Type and Name are object keys.

The secret pudding was the round bracket ( ) around the complex condition.

How neat Javascript has become: no need to get .length nor to loop with 'for' or 'while', no 'if... else' statements, or no need to store interim results, and no 'return'. The arrow replaces all that!

Then you can access eg. Price 'column' as array of numbers for summary calculations (eg. sum of values):

```
var firstSubArrPrice=firstSubArr.map(t => t.Price );
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more and add tell how `json` looks like.

Comment: Do you want it to be just pure js?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get rid of the `map()` and just use `filter()` and you will have the original objects in resultant

```
var firstSubArr = json.filter(function(s) {
  return s.Name === RegName
});
```

Comment: JSON objects will not have a filter option as they are not arrays

Comment: @user37309 No the OP didn't said its object. Its an array of object. as OP used` map()` already

Comment: @user37309 - the OP was doing a `map`, so it's an array.

Comment: Note: `filter()` returns a new array containing the elements where the returned value was `true`.

Comment: Fair - I think he was trying to filter an object though with a certain set of keys

Comment: Yes, this was a good tip! I can still reuse the same complex 'if' condition as in the original function so, unless the arrow function response can be rewritten to include (and shorten?) the condition, this will be the accepted answer...

Comment: Since you weren't using arrow functions and were using regular functions I avoided converting. If you understand arrow functions then it is a simple modification to change it yourself

Comment: Still learning :-) so what it would look like given my Comment 2 example?

Comment: Same concept. Move the conditional logic outside of the `map()` and use it to return a boolean in `filter()`. Can keep that same `if()` and return true and add an else to return false

Answer (score 3):

I understood that you want to return the the object with specific properties which matches the condition.You can do that using `reduce()`

```
var firstSubArr = json.reduce((ac,{Name,Price}) => a.Name === RegName ? [...ac,{Name,Price}] : ac, []);
```

If you don't want only `Name,Price` and all properties with calling names. Then use `filter()` alone

```
var firstSubArr = json.filter(x => x.Name === RegName)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var firstSubArr = json.filter( x => x.Name ===RegName)
```

Comment: This answer is essentially identical to the question!

Comment: Well since they are already objects you just need to filter. Din't geht OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

To make it in JavaScript I recommend this code:

```
var valueNeedly = json.filter(function(s) {
  return s.value === searchValue
});
```